# Client side templating and search engine referencing

Tags: javascript, search-engine, client-side-templating

I keep hearing about javascript templating engines like knockoutjs or backbone recently. They all seem pretty cool but I was wondering if using such systems prevents good indexing of web pages.

Are the search engines' crawlers able to parse the javascript data? I thought it was bad practice to put the page's content in javascript as it was not parsed by some of these crawlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many search engine crawlers now parse JavaScript and will pick up templated content. But there are literally hundreds of crawlers out there and some of the smaller ones still don't understand templates.

If you want full support then server rendered HTML is the only solution. If you're happy just being picked up by the big engines, googlebot, bingbot, baiduspider, etc then JavaScript client side templates can work. But you'll need to check who's picking them up..

Comment: I've been running a test for the last few weeks to see how many crawlers found a templated link. There were very few, like less than 1%. It will depend on the popularity of the template engine and the size of the crawler. We now serve all our templates server-side now because of this..

Comment: We've also detected well over 200 different crawler engines during the test.

Answer (score 0):

Then choose a templating engine that leaves your content inside the HTML like [Distal](http://code.google.com/p/distal).